# DNS analytics solutions?

Tags: dns

Something like http://netfee.ustc.edu.cn/dns/

Showing top DNS queries and top clients etc.

I am not seeing any open source projects doing exactly the same thing, https://www.nanog.org/meetings/nanog55/presentations/Tuesday/Creyts.pdf is somewhere close but still not quite there yet.

How can I build a DNS monitoring system like this with BIND? Packet capturing seems quite inefficient.

Comment: BIND has various, detailed logging facilities. (read any number of man pages, and tutorials explaining those cryptic manpages)

Answer (score 3):

Study BIND's *logging* clause.<sup>[[1](ftp://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind/cur/9.9/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2574875)][[2](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/logging.html)][[3](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/dns/ch07_05.htm)]</sup>

Here's what I've used for decades:

```
logging {
        channel syslog_debug {
                syslog daemon;
                severity debug;
                print-category yes;
                print-severity yes;
        };
        channel statistics_log {
                file "logs/statistics" versions 5 size 10M;
                severity debug;
                print-time yes;
        };
        channel query_log {
                file "logs/querylog" versions 25 size 10M;
                severity debug;
                print-time yes;
        };
        category security       { syslog_debug; };
        category xfer-in        { syslog_debug; };
        category xfer-out       { syslog_debug; };
        category load           { syslog_debug; };
        category statistics     { syslog_debug; statistics_log; };
        category queries        { query_log; };
};
```